# Netbeans is escaping build hints in codenameone_settings.properties file, causing build errors

Tags: codenameone

Netbeans just started automatically escaping some build hints in the codenameone_settings.properties file. The build server seems to reject this. I've never seen this behavior, I haven't been able to find any way to stop it. An example:

```
codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

gets turned into:

```
codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans is correct in doing that. It should be escaped. If you look at the top of the build error you will see the string the server received for the build hints and you will see the string isn't escaped there.

The reason for the failure of the build is probably something else.